# c#remote client server getting client id

Tags: c#

Server

```
        BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider cli = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();
        BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider slv = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
        slv.TypeFilterLevel = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Full;
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht["port"] = 2000;
        TcpChannel c = new TcpChannel(ht, cli, slv);
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(c, false);
        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(remotobject), "chatUri", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
        Console.WriteLine("Sunucu aktif");
        string[] urls = c.GetUrlsForUri("chatUri");
```

Client

```
BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider cli = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();
        BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider slv = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
        slv.TypeFilterLevel = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Full;
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht["port"] = 0;
        TcpChannel c = new TcpChannel(ht, cli, slv);
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(c, false);
        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType(typeof(remotobject), "tcp://" + txtSunucu.Text.Trim() + ":2000/chatUri");
```

So this are my client and server what i want to know is how can i find the client id in the connection for private messaging ?

Comment: What do you mean by `client id`?

Comment: that client is actually part of a long client form app and i want to add pm feature to code to do that i need an id ,ip or something like that send message not to chat  room but just one client